# Download MacOS Mojave to USB-Drive from a Windows PC [MacStore not accessible without Mac?]

Tags: mojave, usb, mac-appstore, catalina

I'm having a very hard time repairing a broken Mojave->Catalina update on a MacBook Pro from 2015 for a friend of mine.

This is what happened:
After doing the Update, the Mac wouldn't start up anymore (stating "couldn't install Catalina").

I tried to finish it in internet recovery mode without success, couldn't even do a backup. I did the backup via Terminal onto an external hdd.

Hardware check states all hardware is OK.
There are sadly no timemachine backups available as the user didn't backup.

Order of what i have tried so far:

```
#1 installation of Catalina fails at bootup with message "error creating kernel caches"
#2 recovery mode attemps to finish Catalina install, after finishing bootup again fails with message "error creating kernel caches"
#3 resetting NVRAM does not help
#4 internet recovery mode: same error
#5 use DiskUtil to backup Data - after running for some time fails with read/write error
#6 why did DiskUtil fail? 'DiskUtil list' shows 19 volumes - googling points me to Catalina-Installer bug which creates spurious additional drives
#7 how to fix this? no idea
#8 backup files using terminal to a external hdd
#8 try Catalina Install from USB 
#9 realize there is no way of creating a Mac-OS USB from Windows or Linux
#10 realize it isn't even possible to download the image from win/linux
#11 being frustrated with Apple
```

It seems that during the update, the Catalina-Installer made spurious additional volumes, like stated [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/12/21/what-to-do-when-a-macos-update-goes-wrong-catalina-edition/). I have no idea how to fix this besides trying a clean install from a USB - which i don't even know if it will work.

Im stuck at this for far too long, Apple support hasn't been helpful either.

Comment: I read this as "I tried to finish the Catalina upgrade through Recovery" which isn't the same as re-installing Mojave (or whatever version Recovery Mode wants to install). Nevertheless there is no official way to download macOS from outside the store and using Recovery is the standard way of getting back to a bootable Mac. Have you tried all the methods outlined in https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204904 yet?

Comment: If none of the Recovery methods work, please describe in more detail *how* they fail so we can work based on that. Alternatively anybody with a Mac can download Mojave for you and create a bootable Flash drive.